# AttributeError in Python Static Method

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, python-3.6

I'm trying to create a class `USTradingCalendar` with only static methods in Python 3.6.

**Problem:** However when I try to call the static method `get_trading_close_holidays()`, I get an error

```
AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'rules'
```

What went wrong? Any help appreciated!

```
import datetime as dt
from helpers import str2date

from pandas.tseries.holiday import AbstractHolidayCalendar, Holiday, nearest_workday, \
    USMartinLutherKingJr, USPresidentsDay, GoodFriday, USMemorialDay, \
    USLaborDay, USThanksgivingDay


class USTradingCalendar(AbstractHolidayCalendar):
    rules = [
        Holiday('NewYearsDay', month=1, day=1, observance=nearest_workday),
        USMartinLutherKingJr,
        USPresidentsDay,
        GoodFriday,
        USMemorialDay,
        Holiday('USIndependenceDay', month=7, day=4, observance=nearest_workday),
        USLaborDay,
        USThanksgivingDay,
        Holiday('Christmas', month=12, day=25, observance=nearest_workday)
    ]


    @classmethod
    def get_trading_close_holidays(cls, year):
        return cls.holidays(dt.datetime(year-1, 12, 31), dt.datetime(year, 12, 31))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(USTradingCalendar.get_trading_close_holidays(2016))
```

**Traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tradingCalendar.py", line 37, in <module>
    print(USTradingCalendar.get_trading_close_holidays(2016))
  File "tradingCalendar.py", line 32, in get_trading_close_holidays
    return cls.holidays(dt.datetime(year-1, 12, 31), dt.datetime(year, 12, 31))
  File "C:\Users\y\Anaconda2\envs\test\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\holiday.py", line 376, in holidays
    if self.rules is None:
AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'rules'
```

Comment: please post the entire traceback

Comment: @0TTT0 Updated OP with traceback

Comment: @gommb Yes works great. Is this because `USTradingCalendar` is kind of like `self` in `holidays(self,...`?

Comment: In this case yes that is correct since you are calling `holidays()` statically. If you called `holidays()` from an instance of `USTradingCalendar` then you would not have to enter anything for `self`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`holidays()` requires an argument of type `AbstractHolidayCalendar` so change it to this:

```
@classmethod
def get_trading_close_holidays(cls, year):
    return cls.holidays(USTradingCalendar(), dt.datetime(year-1, 12, 31), dt.datetime(year, 12, 31))
```